# Best practice regarding number of threads in GUI applications

Tags: user-interface, language-agnostic

In the past I've worked with a number of programmers who have worked exclusively writing GUI applications.

And I've been given the impression that they have almost universally minimised the use of multiple threads in their applications. In some cases they seem to have gone to extreme lengths to ensure that they use a single thread.

Is this common? Is this the generally accepted philosophy for gui application design?

And if so, why?

[edit]

There are a number of answers saying that thread usage should be minimised to reduce complexity. Reducing complexity in general is a good thing.

But if you look at any number of applications where response to external events is of paramount importance (eg. web servers, any number of embedded applications) there seems to be a world of difference in the attitude toward thread usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen the same thing.  Ideally you should perform any operation that is going to take longer then a few hundred ms in a background thread.  Anything sorter than 100ms and a human probably wont notice the difference.

A lot of GUI programmers I've worked with in the past are scared of threads because they are "hard".  In some GUI frameworks such as the Delphi VCL there are warnings about using the VCL from multiple threads, and this tends to scare some people (others take it as a challenge ;) )

One interesting example of multi-threaded GUI coding is the BeOS API.  Every window in an application gets its own thread.  From my experience this made BeOS apps feel more responsive, but it did make programming things a little more tricky.  Fortunately since BeOS was designed to be multi-threaded by default there was a lot of stuff in the API to make things easier than on some other OSs I've used.

Answer (score 5):

I think in terms of windows you are limited to all GUI operations happening on a single thread - because of the way the windows message pump works, to increase responsivness most apps add at least one additional worker thread for longer running tasks that would otherwise block and make the ui unresponsive.

Threading is fundamentally hard and so thinking in terms or more than a couple threads can often result in a lot of debugging effort - there is a quote that escapes me right now that goes something like - "if you think you understand threading then you really dont"

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, GUI frameworks aren't thread safe.  For things like Swing(Java's GUI API), only one thread can be updating the UI (or bad things can happen).  Only one thread handles dispatching events.  If you have multiple threads updating the screen, you can get some ugly flicker and incorrect drawing.

That doesn't mean the application needs to be single threaded, however.  There are certainly circumstances when you don't want this to be the case.  If you click on a button that calculates pi to 1000 digits, you don't want the UI to be locked up and the button to be depressed for the next couple of days.  This is when things like SwingWorker come in handy.  It has two parts a doInBackground() which runs in a seperate thread  and a done() that gets called by the thread that handles updating the UI sometime after the doInBackground thread has finished.  This allows events to be handled quickly, or events that would take a long time to process in the background, while still having the single thread updating the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Most GUI frameworks are not thread safe, meaning that all controls have to me accessed from the same thread that created them. Still, it's a good practice to create worker threads to have responsive applications, but you need to be careful to delegate GUI updates to the GUI thread.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

GUI applications should minimize the the number of threads that they use for the following reasons:

1. Thread programming is very hard and complicated
2. In general, GUI applications do at most 2 things at once : a) Respond to User Input, and b) Perform a background task (such as load in data) in response to a user action or an anticipated user action

***In general*** therefore, the added complexity of using multiple threads is not justified by the needs of the application.

There are of course exceptions to the rule.

Answer (score 1):

GUIs generally don't use a whole lot of threads, but they often do throw off another thread for interacting with certain sub-systems especially if those systems take awhile or are very shared resources.

For example, if you're going to print, you'll often want to throw off another thread to interact with the printer pool as it may be very busy for awhile and there's no reason not to keep working.

Another example would be database loads where you're interacting with SQL server or something like that and because of the latency involved you may want to create another thread so your main UI processing thread can continue to respond to commands.

Answer (score 1):

The more threads you have in an application, (generally) the more complex the solution is. By attempting to minimise the number of threads being utilised within a GUI, there are less potential areas for problems.

The other issue is the biggest problem in GUI design: the human. Humans are notorious in their *in*ability to want to do multiple things at the same time. Users have a habit of clicking multiple butons/controls in quick sucession in order to attempt to get something done quicker. Computers cannot generally keep up with this (this is only componded by the GUIs apparent ability to keep up by using multiple threads), so to minimise this effect GUIs will respond to input on a first come first serve basis on a single thread. By doing this, the GUI is forced to wait until system resorces are free untill it can move on. Therefore elimating all the nasty deadlock situations that can arise. Obviously if the program logic and the GUI are on different threads, then this goes out the window.

From a personal preference, I prefer to keep things simple on one thread but not to the detriment of the responsivness of the GUI. If a task is taking too long, then Ill use a different thread, otherwise Ill stick to just one.

Answer (score 1):

As the prior comments said, GUI Frameworks (at least on Windows) are single threaded, thus the single thread. Another recommendation (that is difficult to code in practice) is to limit the number of the threads to the number of available cores on the machine. Your CPU can only do one operation at a time with one core. If there are two threads, a context switch has to happen at some point. If you've got too many threads, the computer can sometimes spend more time swapping between threads than letting threads work.

As Moore's Law changes with more cores, this will change and hopefully programming frameworks will evolve to help us use threads more effectively, depending on the number of cores available to the program, such as the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163340.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Generally all the windowing messages from the window manager / OS will go to a single queue so its natural to have all UI elements in a single thread.  Some frameworks, such as .Net, actually throw exceptions if you attempt to directly access UI elements from a thread other than the thread that created it.