# How to calculate maximum and minimum number of web container threads in web server e.g. Tomcat, WAS

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat

I would like to understand how to calculate maximum and minimum number of web container threads in web server e.g. Tomcat, WAS. I would like to understand optimum threads configuration for maximum performance.

Thanks is advance!

I found answer in thread below

[How many simultaneous threads in an application is a lot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363079/how-many-simultaneous-threads-in-an-application-is-a-lot/363166#363166)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no optimum thread configuration as such. It depends upon your peak / concurrent load requirements which in turn affects your hardware / memory requirements too. What you would want to make sure is that there are enough threads to handle that load within accepted time limits. Running a load testing tool should give you enough inputs to begin with.