# Can GSubprocess be used in a thread safely?

Tags: c, concurrency, segmentation-fault, subprocess, gtk

I ran across some problems with GtkSubprocess, and I figured out that it is related to using threads, and is there a way to make it immune to concurrency problems?

I have this program that does some operations on a file, which are individually represented by `GtkListBoxRow`s. When the GSubprocess finishes, and I attempt to remove the list box row, the program segfaults. BTW, each file has its own process, so if a user loads 10 files, there will be 10 threads (this is managed by `GThreadPool`). Interestingly, if I comment out the code that launches the process, and the code that blocks the thread function till the process finishes, the program does not segfault. So I deduced that `GSubprocess` is having problems with concurrency. The error produced varies a lot, so this must be due to time-related problems.

I wanted to use `GSubprocess` because it is relatively easy to get the output of the command, which I need. Will I need to move my invocations of GSubprocess outside of the thread function?

Comment: The question you link to never mentions GSubprocess, only the Python-specific `subprocess` module (which is not based on the Gtk gsubprocess).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it is not safe, due to its internal implementation in the GTK+ source code. And you should not even use threads in an application as well, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120636/best-practice-regarding-number-of-threads-in-gui-applications). Here is my workaround: create the process in the main loop, and wait for the process to terminate using the [async](https://docs.gtk.org/gio/method.Subprocess.wait_async.html) version of the call. Thus you avoid threads.